# Is This Database Reference to Firebase Realtime Database Correct?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to access values stored in the realtime database and display it on the table. I just wanted to double check, if i wanted to access the value of 'milk' in this database section, is my reference right? Thanks

```
 databaseRef =  Database.database().reference().child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser)/Journal/")
```

[image: User id -> Journal -> Date Added -> Items -> Grocery -> Milk]

Comment: That code looks fine to me. If you have any problems with it, edit your question to show the [minimal-but-complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You should change your reference to

```
databaseRef =  Database.database().reference().child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser)).child("Journal")
```

If you want to access the value of "milk", you need to add more child.